# AWS EC2 Autoscaling: Defining a master instance, which is never terminated

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, autoscaling

I am using EC2 with autoscaling and loadbalancing to host my webapp. To guarantee consistency between the EC2 instances, I only want to allow access to the administration interface from one instance, so all write operations are executed on this instance. The other instaces then periodically download copies of the changed files.

So here's my question:

Can I have a designated "Master" Instance, in my autoscaling group, which is slightly different (runs script for uploading files which were written to)? Of course this Instance should never be shut down, no matter what. All the other "Slave" Instances are indentical an can be created and terminated on demand. Is there some sort of configuration option for this or can I do this with a policy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My suggestion would be one of two things, either have two autoscaling groups - one for the readonly instances (i.e. the non-master), and then a second ASG for the master instance(s). Even if there is only one master instance at any time, you can still benefit by including it in its own autoscaling group by taking advantage of the ability for the ASG to detect when it has failed, and spin up a single new instance to replace it.

Alternatively, leave the master instance out of the auto-scaling altogether, and just run it as a reserved instances - let the rest of the RO instances scale up and down as necessary.