# Autoscaling Jenkins instance by auto creating new slave machines

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, jenkins-agent

I am currently implementing autoscaling on a Jenkins server.  I am hosting Jenkins on an ec2 instance.

I want to enable new Jenkins slave instances on demand.

I have followed the instructions here https://medium.com/@DoctorNantucket/auto-scaling-jenkins-builders-with-packer-ansible-and-aws-e84f4d0a3853.  However, when I click on “Provision via ”, the instance is created and connecting to it on port 22 results in an error.

The instance is created, and I have validated that the security group that I am adding has port 22 open in the Inbound Rules.

Does anyone know the reason for this error?  Once fixed, will the Jenkins Slaves be created on demand? - What determines whether they are needed?  Is an autoscaling group set up in AWS a more stable and scalable approach (e.g. [AWS EC2 Autoscaling: Defining a master instance, which is never terminated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27666469/aws-ec2-autoscaling-defining-a-master-instance-which-is-never-terminated?rq=1)) ?

Comment: did you try to trigger an AWS machine and connect it to the master manually ?  I suggest to do it manually and than understand what's the problem.  what is the error you get ?